# C# parse datetime from string \/Date(1433969291760)\/

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I recieved a string from url   "/Date(1433969291760)/", I want to parse this string to datetime mm-dd-yyyy by C# code. help me !!!
thank advance!!!

Comment: OK, it would help to know what format the date is in that you get from the URL?

Answer (score 3):

Newtonsoft JSON.NET can handle these kinds of dates directly.

```
string s = "\"/Date(1433969291760)/\"";
var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(s);
```